# Is there a way to know which item has the focus in a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, debugging, focus

I there a way to know which item has the focus in and WPF application?
Is there a way to monitor all events and methods calls in wpf?

Comment: Did the solution ever work for you?

Comment: Actually I used UISpy which does track the focus of items

Comment: I used similar tool - Inspect (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64\inspect.exe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok on this page you'll find a solution but it's a bit nasty if you ask me:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a420dc50-b238-4d2e-9209-dfbd98c7a060

It uses the VisualTreeHelper to create a big list of all the controls out there and then asks them is they have the focus by lookin at the IsFocused property.

I would think that there is a better way to do it.
Perhaps do a search for Active control or Focussed control in combination with WPF.

EDIT:
This topic might be useful
[How to programmatically navigate WPF UI element tab stops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809382/how-to-programmatically-navigate-wpf-ui-element-tab-stops)

Answer (score 5):

```
FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this); // where this is Window1
```

Here's a full sample (when the app runs, focus a textbox and hit enter)

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowTests.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" KeyDown="window1_KeyDown"
    Title="Window1" x:Name="window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" />
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" />
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox3" />
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox4" />
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox5" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace StackOverflowTests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void window1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Key == Key.Return)
                MessageBox.Show((FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as FrameworkElement).Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I returns null, if focused element is window.